# How to find a div with a specific id name and iterate over its children using lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

I am using Python lxml client and I tried the following code to parse and get the elements I want but it just returns empty:

```
from lxml import html
tree = html.fromstring(html_content)
posts = tree.xpath('//*[@id="posts"]/div')
for post in posts:
    print post
```

The HTML code looks like the following:

```
<div>
  <div>
    ...
     <div id="posts">
         <div>
             <div class="post"> 
                 <a href="">User 1</a>
                 <div class="content"> Content 1</div>
             </div>
             <div class="post"> 
                 <a href="">User 2</a>
                 <div class="content"> Content 2</div>
             </div>
             ...
         </div>
     </div>
   ...
```

I would like to iterate over each `post` so that I access `<a>` tag and `<div>` contents. I would like to print:

```
 User 1
 Content 1

 User 2
 Content 2

 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be easier to target the tags with class `post` with a similar syntax :

```
posts = tree.xpath('//*[@id="posts"]/div/*[@class="post"]')
for post in posts:
    print post.find('a').text
    print post.find('div').text # add .strip() to clean the leading space
```

outputs :

```
User 1
 Content 1

User 2
 Content 2
```

Comment: The issue with above is that `post` class is used a lot within the page. I am only interested with `post` that are children of `posts` id.